# Does need connect to local mbean server to access nested mbeans?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

When I connect with JConsole I see that some beans nested inside others.
To access to nested beans must I create to mbean server?
Usually I give access like to spring beans (in description of bean I put names of beans that I need)
Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "nested mbean". Do you refer to the tree structure that JConsole uses to visualize the mbean object names?

Comment: Yes, I refer to tree structure that I see in JConsole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree structure that Jconsole uses to display mbeans is simply a reflection of the structure of mbean object names: `domain:key=val,key=val,...`. The presentation could equally well be a simple flat list. This has nothing to with how you access mbeans.

You always access mbeans through an MBean server connection, local or remote, using the mbean object name.